# Is it possible to include a web.config file (or equivalent) for a PHP Web App on Azure?

Tags: php, asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to restrict access to my PHP site to a specific IP address, but the only [type of documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/ip-and-domain-restrictions-for-windows-azure-web-sites/) I've seen for doing this uses a web.config file. I know web.config is normally used in ASP.NET projects, but don't' know if we're supposed to be able to include it somewhere in a PHP project. I've tried including an empty file named web.config in my web root, but `The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.` is displayed as the page when requesting the site.

Is there a proper place to stick this in my directory, a specific way to configure it, or another type of file I can include somewhere that is equivalent to the web.config?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely do this using a php page and web.config. Make sure the web.config is placed in the root folder of the website.

Please see my code below that worked perfect. I pushed to the following website for testing: http://php-ip-restrict-110515.azurewebsites.net/

My index.php file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

<?php
 echo "My test PHP script!";
 ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

My web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<configuration> 
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false" denyAction="NotFound">
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" />
        </ipSecurity>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Make sure to replace XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX with your Ip Address.

Comment: So the file can't be empty and needs to be configured properly. I had previously tried another configuration example but I guess the settings in it didn't work with my site. Thank you!

Comment: Fun fact, if you upload just a PHP file via Git, Kudu (the backend for Web Apps) will create a Web.config for you. So you go to `<your_site>.scm.azurewebsites.net` and use the file browser, you'll find the web.config that's automatically generated if you don't specify one.

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT Thanks, I found a file named rootweb.config after uploading a project without my own web.config, but I don't seem to have the permissions to edit it. I was wondering if you have anymore fun facts regarding the editing of this file.

Comment: Is it in your wwwroot folder?